# Searching the minimum value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a program with C which has to search the minimum value of a vector but I'm doing something wrong. With the numbers1,2,3,4,5 in the vector it works correctly, but then, when I try it with the numbers: 22, 72, 123, 45, 81 it says to me that the minimum one is 45.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAX= 5;

int main(){
    int vector[MAX], i=0;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        cin>>vector[i];
    }
    int min=vector[0], posicio;
    for(i=1;i<MAX;i++){
        if(vector[i]<vector[i-1]){
            min=vector[i];
            posicio= i;
        }
    }
    cout<<min<<"#"<<posicio<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean C++? You tagged it as C++, use some C++ features, but you say C.

Comment: If you program in C, why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: take sheet of paper and pencil and examine what happens in your second loop - then the solution will be obvious....

Comment: What about changing your condition to `if(vector[i]<min){`?

Comment: Consider what happens if no input is given, or if some is given, but not as much as you expect. Will your program respond correctly? In addition, the whole `min` loop can be replaced by a call to `std::min_element`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only picking two elements from your vector to compare these:

```
 if(vector[i]<vector[i-1]){
```

so that condition only gives you the minimum of these two, and not that of the whole array.

Change your condition to

```
 if(vector[i]<min){
```

and your code will run as intended.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the variable `posicio` was not initialized. So in general case the program has undefined behavior.

And secondly you are finding the last element in the vector such that the condition `vector[i]<vector[i-1]` is true. And indeed for this sequence
22, 72, 123, 45, 81  such an element is 45.

If you need to find the minimum element ypu should write

```
int min=vector[0], posicio = 0;
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
for(i=1;i<MAX;i++){
    if( vector[i] < min ){
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        min=vector[i];
        posicio= i;
    }
}
```

If you need to determine only the position of the minimum element of the array then you can write

```
int posicio = 0;

for ( i = 1; i < MAX; i++ ){
    if( vector[i] < vector[posicio} ){
        posicio = i;
    }
}
```

And it does not make sense to declare the variable `i` outside the loops.

So you may remove this declaration

```
   int vector[MAX], i=0;
                  ^^^^^
```

And write for example

```
for ( int i = 0;i < MAX; i++ ){
    cin >> vector[i];
}
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::min_element` declared in header `<algorithm>` that performs this task.